# How can I read the Key name from App.Config?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have some key value pairs stored in the App.Config.

Now I want to read the Key name instead of the Value, and I can't seem to figure it out.

```
string test = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["keyname"];
```

I want to store the name in a new variable but the only method of doing this I found online, only gets the key.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.AllKeys`. It pays to explore and research the APIs you are uisng.

Comment: Perfect thanks a lot!